# Scrolling height bug using skrollr.js on safari ios7

Tags: javascript, ios7, mobile-safari, parallax, skrollr

I've been racking my brain trying to understand what I'm doing wrong. I'm using prinzhorn's skrollr.js for scrolling animation effects on my portfolio redesign and it works great on desktop and even chrome for ios7.

But...when loading in safari ios7 it scrolls only so far (to the brand logos section) then stops before reaching the end of the page. Only when I change the orientation to landscape, then back to portrait does it correct itself.

I've also noticed some strange inconsistencies when I reload. Sometimes it will scroll a little farther, sometimes a little shorter. And my initial logo (AP) at the top of the page will disappear sometimes until I initiate scrolling.

Anyone have any thoughts? Markup mistake? I tried messing the the "forceHeight: false" but to no avail. I've been removing and shifting around things but that doesn't help either. I even added my "clearfix" class but still having issues. I'm sure I'm being a dummy about it. Any insights would help immensely.
Demo link below:

http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35202847/portfolio_v7/about.html

Comment: I guess it's a timing issue, because you're calling `init` before all images have been loaded. Try calling the `refresh` method after the window load event.

Comment: @Prinzhorn, Thanks for responding! So I updated the code to this at the bottom:

`

<script src="js/skrollr.js"></script> 
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
   var s = skrollr.init({
    
    forceHeight:false
    
    
    });

});

</script> 

`

Wrapped it in a 'Document Ready' function, still having the safari issues

I'm not sure how to call the refresh method as you're recommending, looking at the docs right now, any chance you can point me in the right direction with my code? I'm not the biggest javascript whiz.

Comment: `var s = skrollr.init()` later `s.refresh()` or even `skrollr.get().refresh()` at any point after initialization

Comment: ahhhh, so what I ended up doing was
`window.onload=function(){s.refresh()};` inside of a document ready function. I feel like my phone is doing a little extra thinking, but it did the trick. Thanks!